# Creating one user access account for all the multiple sites

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, multisite, membership, development-strategy

I am new to WordPress and ill just state the situation.

We have multiple websites created independently and I need to create a single account for the subscribers for all the websites like google.

I am asking for advice and help on how to build this and I read multiple forums that WPMU is capable of doing this but it has limits like for example it throws the WordPress wp-admin as a login page maybe I need a custom login and dashboard for users/subscribers and monitor each of there activities like example we have an e-commerce website that needs an account before purchasing same to the blog websites that needs an account first to access contents and an e-learning website accessible with one account  just like google but on WordPress platform

Can you guide me on how to do this like tools/knowledge?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: >'need to create a single account for the subscribers for all the websites like google." , What you mean by like Google ? Can you give more details

Comment: I see you don't need one account for all users , you need one account per user for all multiple sites. So if i create a user account I can access all of your site's with one login... Sorry you may add this in question as it looked like you wanted one account for everyone.. my bad

Comment: basically, like Google, if you sign up you can have multiple websites access like youtube, mails and etc.

Comment: I found this video (https://vimeo.com/62042591) on how to have a single table for users but multiple WordPress installations but in one database. What are the Pros and Cons of this setup.

Comment: What you're describing is called "single sign on". If you use this phrase you might have more luck finding solutions.